# How do I add classes in a linked list of users?

Tags: java, oop, linked-list, addition

How should I add a whole class in a linked list that also has arguments such as name, password and a boolean to check if it's connected to a server?

The strange thing about this issue is that the User is successfully registered in the `User.java`, but not in the `UserRegistery.java`.

```
public class User {

    private String name = "";
    private String password = "";
    private String email = "";

    private boolean connection;

    public User(String name, String password, boolean connection){

        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.connection = connection;

        setUserName(name);
        setUserPassword(password);
        setUserConnection(connection);
        System.out.println("Client Created : User ["+format()+"]");
    }

    public void setUserName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUserName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUserPassword(){
        return password;
    }   

    public void setUserEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUserEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public void setUserConnection(boolean connection){
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public boolean getUserConnection(){
        return connection;
    }

    public String format(){
        return String.format("%-5s, %-5s, %s" , getUserName(), 
                getUserPassword(), getUserConnection());
    }
}
```

```
public class UserRegistry {

    private LinkedList<User> users;
    private User user;
    private String name = "", password = "";
    private boolean conn = false;

    //Constructor:
    public UserRegistry() { //Setting new students in the Linked List
        users = new LinkedList<User>();
    }

    public void addUser(User aUser) {
        System.out.println("Waiting to "
            + "add user to the server . . . ");

        users.add(aUser);
        System.out.println("Client Creation "
            + ": Confirmed !!! ");

        System.out.println("Client Creation "
            + ": Declined !!! ");
    }


}
```

This is the output I get:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where did you create the `registration`shown in the screenshot?  Be also more precise on your problem - is it the NPE?

Comment: Did you ever called `users.add(aUser)`? And why did you wrote "Confirmed" AND "Declined" without checking/validating?

Comment: @zlakad I think that is shown in the image displayed when clicking on the link "CLICK HERE TO SEE..."

Comment: Hello @Stefan Freitag, the registration is created in the main method and i pass it as an argument to get to the needed place...
**MAIN METHOD --->** UserRegistry registration = new UserRegistry();
frame = new ServerFrame(registration);     
**SERVER FRAME --->** In the constructor I set the UserRegistry as an argument and then I use ----->this.registration = registration; and I pass it to the panel MainPanel main_Panel = new MainPanel(registration) ---> **MAIN PANEL ---> **I do the same in constructor and then i call a method **SIGNUP METHOD --->** calls registration.addUser(new User()

Comment: @zlakad I call the users.add(aUser); in the **UserRegistry.java -> method: public void addUser(User aUser);**

Comment: In UserRegistry.java, method isn't called, it is declared. Also, from your picture, it is said that some exception occurred in MainPanel.java line 202?

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou please check if the registration is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @zlakad .. What do u mean is not called, it is declared??The line 202 is where I call the method that calls the registration.addUser(new User());

Comment: @StefanFreitag you are a god.. I used if(registration != null){
            frame = new ServerFrame(registration);     
        } and fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Is your `'registration'` variable in `MainPanel.java` initialized? By the way, you do not need to call setters inside User constructor and you also do not need that part in `UserRegistry.java`:

```
private User user;
private String name = "", password = "";
private boolean conn = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the provided screenshot, the `registration` is null. Please fix this.